# An alternative method for JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript

I want an alternative method for JSON.stringify(). 
I am using JSON.stringify and I got error like cyclic object value. I don't know how to remove this error so I'd like to know if there's an alternative method.

```
DCSSPACE.SaveAndOpenJSONWriter = function(canvas) {

    //multiple tab.....
    var mydata = [];
    var area = {}, DCS = {}, workspace = {};
    var len = DCSSPACE.collection.length;
    for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
        var result = [];
        var tabid = DCSSPACE.collection.models[k].id;
        var canvas = DCSSPACE.collection.get(tabid).get("workflow");
        //for node
        var figures = canvas.getFigures();
        for (var i = 0; i < figures.getSize(); i++) {
            if (figures.get(i).type == "draw2d.Node") {
                var node = {};

                node.blockType = getBlockType(figures.get(i));
                node.x = figures.get(i).getX();
                node.y = figures.get(i).getY();
                node.id = figures.get(i).getId();
                node.type = figures.get(i).type;
                node.width = figures.get(i).getWidth();
                node.height = figures.get(i).getHeight();
                node.label = figures.get(i).getLabel();
                node.sequenceNo = figures.get(i).getSequenceNo();
            node.model = figures.get(i).model;

                result.push(node);
            }
        }
        //for lines
        var lines = canvas.getLines();
        for (var j = 0; j < lines.getSize(); j++) {
            if (lines.get(j).type == "draw2d.nodeConnetion") {
                var nodeConnection = lines.get(j).getConnectionAttrubutes();

                nodeConnection.source = lines.get(j).getSource();
                nodeConnection.target = lines.get(j).getTarget();
                result.push(nodeConnection);
            }
        }
        area = {
            tabid : tabid,
            attr : result
        };

        mydata.push(area);
        result=[];
        workspace = {
            DCS : mydata
        };
    }
    //console.log(mydata);
    var arr = JSON.stringify(workspace, null, 4);
    console.log(arr);
    DCSSPACE.SaveAndLoadFigure = result;

    return workspace;

};
```

Comment: Can you replicate this in a Fiddle or at least include the error message in the question?

Comment: The error message means that you have a reference to the object itself, which would create an infinite loop when trying to stringify it. Find which key holds the reference, remove it, and you're good to go.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a cyclic Object graph?

Comment: `var arr = JSON.stringify(workspace, null, 4)` you only use this for read the json?
But console.log can read a object... and show you the structure...
You can use `console.log(workspace)` and read the response tree in the console...

Answer (score 3):

If won't to use stringify you can reproduce it, like this:

`OBJtoString(object [,n])` accempt 2 args:

- `object` (needed) the object you need to log (in my release array and object is the same)
- `n` numbero of space that indent every new line inside object aruments.

  ```
  var OBJtoString = function(_o,_m,_rf,_dep,_res){
      _dep = [],
      _rf = function(obj,n,_n,_a,_k,_i,_ws,_f,_e){
          if(typeof obj != "object") return false;
          if(typeof _a === "undefined") _a = "FIRST PARENT OBJECT";
          _dep.push(obj),
          _f = (_dep.length < 1) ? function(){} : function(_z,_x){
              for(_x = 0; _x <= _dep.length; _x++){
                  if(obj[_z] == _dep[_x]) return true;
              }
              return false;
          }
          _ws = "";
          if(typeof n === "undefined") n = 1;
          if(typeof _n === "undefined") _n = n;
          for(_k = 0; _k <= n; _k++){
              _ws += " ";
          }
          var response ="{ \n";
          for(var _i in obj){
              if(typeof obj[_i] !== "object"){
              if(typeof obj[_i] === "string") obj[_i] = "'"+obj[_i].toString()+"'";
              if(typeof obj[_i] === "boolean") obj[_i] = obj[_i].toString() + " (boolean)";
              response += _ws + _i + " : " + obj[_i].toString();
              response += "\n";
              continue;
          }
              response += (_f(_i)) ? _ws + _i + " : "+ _a +" (prevent loop)\n" : _ws + _i + " : " + _rf(obj[_i],n+_n,_n,_a);
          }
      if(_n != n) response += _ws;
      return response +="} \n";
      }
  _res = _rf(_o,_m);
  _dep = [];
  return _res;
   }
  ```

#### Uses Example:

```
var example = {ciao : "hellow", saluto : {ciao : "ciao", dam : true}};
example.parentObj = example;
console.log(OBJtoString(example,4));
```

#### return:

```
 { 
     ciao : 'hellow'
     saluto : { 
          ciao : 'ciao'
          dam : true (boolean)
     }
     parentObj : FIRST PARENT OBJECT (prevent loop)
}
```

#### Other Example:

```
var example = {ciao : "hellow", saluto : {ciao : "ciao", dam : true}};
example.parentObj = example;
example.f = {
    g : example
}
console.log(OBJtoString(example,4));
```

#### Return:

```
{ 
     ciao : 'hellow'
     saluto : { 
         ciao : 'ciao'
         dam : true (boolean)
         } 
     parentObj : FIRST PARENT OBJECT (prevent loop)
     f : { 
         g : FIRST PARENT OBJECT (prevent loop)
         } 
}
```

Comment: This technique would still have a problem with cyclic structures, just like the native impls.

Comment: code UPDATE to prevent loop when the object has itself like a prop. take a look... solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found util.inspect() pretty helpful.

You can print entire object
`console.log(util.inspect(myObj))`

Or with optional arguments
`util.inspect(object, showHidden=false, depth=2, colorize=true)`

Documentation:
https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/how-to-use-util-inspect/