# JSON.stringify is very slow for large objects

Tags: javascript, json, performance

I have a very big object in javascript (about 10MB).

And when I stringify it, it takes a long time, so I send it to backend and parse it to an object( actually nested objects with arrays), and that takes long time too but it's not our problem in this question.

**The problem:**

How can I make `JSON.stringify` faster, any ideas or alternatives, I need a javaScript solution, libraries I can use or ideas here.

**What I've tried**

I googled a lot and looks there is no better performance than `JSON.stringify` or my googling skills got rusty!

**Result**

I accept any suggestion that may solve me the long saving (sending to backend) in the request (I know its big request).

**Code Sample of problem (details about problem)**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8081/systemName/controllerA/update.html;jsessionid=FB3848B6C0F4AD9873EA12DBE61E6008
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

Am sending a POST to backend and then in **JAVA**

request.getParameter("BigPostParameter")

and I read it to convert to object using

```
 public boolean fromJSON(String string) {
        if (string != null && !string.isEmpty()) {
            ObjectMapper json = new ObjectMapper();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(YYYY_MM_DD_T_HH_MM_SS_SSS_Z);
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            json.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
            json.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
            WebObject object;
//            Logger.getLogger("JSON Tracker").log(Level.SEVERE, "Start");
            try {
                object = json.readValue(string, this.getClass());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JSON_ERROR).log(Level.SEVERE, "JSON Error: {0}", ex.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
//            Logger.getLogger("JSON Tracker").log(Level.SEVERE, "END");
            return this.setThis(object);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Like This**

```
BigObject someObj = new BigObject();
someObj.fromJSON(request.getParameter("BigPostParameter"))
```

**P.S** : FYI this line  `object = json.readValue(string, this.getClass());`
is also very very very slow.

**Again to summarize**

- Problem in posting time (stringify) JavaScript bottle nick.
- Another problem parsing that stringified into an object (using jackson), and mainly I have svg tags content in that stringified object as a style column, and other columns are strings,  int mainly

Comment: How do you send it to a backend without converting it to JSON?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` is recursive. Why is `JSON.stringify()` call necessary?
 What is application and expected result?

Comment: For serialization, you're going to be hard-pressed to find a faster alternative unless you look into designing or replicating a byte-encoded format. If you're hard-set on JSON format, `JSON.stringify()` is probably the fastest you'll get, though. There are other methods I know of that utilize streaming to be more _memory efficient_, but not _faster_.

Comment: A 10 MB object will take a considerable time to be processed, there is no way around that directly. Posing a question looking for a workaround would be akin to asking how to make a big file download faster: sure you can cut some time here and there, but there is still an enormous amount of data to be processed, and that will take time. You'll need to design your UX around this.

Comment: Is this a perceptual (UI hangs/blocked interactions, etc.) or performance issue (you actually need the data to be serialized faster)?  If the issue is perceptual, you may want to look into handling the operation using the [Service Worker APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)

Comment: @JohnWeisz , you know i have a big feature built in our system , its using fabric.js to build plans with lot of different objects(nested) , and its rendered to the user as svg , the problem i need fast,temp solution, until we re build it with svg to make changes only that are sent to server instead of sending all and resaving it again, i agree with UI idea, and i believe there is no majic here. but any hint would help me

Comment: Is the issue requesting data or response from server?

Comment: problem posting time ( stringify) and other problem parsing that stringified into object (using jackson)  , and mainly i have svg tags content in that stringified object as style column , and other columns are strings ,int mainly

Comment: I'm inclined to say this is too broad, because the solution is to cache and/or break up the object, or both. There are no faster serializers: see https://github.com/kawanet/msgpack-lite

Comment: @MeirionHughes this implies rewrite and recommendation to not ever design with large `JSON` s expected correct ? is that an answer am asking for smart solution until i re write .

Comment: Technical debt... time to pay the piper.

Comment: Thanks all, `backend problem` what i ended up doing is , optimizing back end by using comparator for the json that comes and one from database to compare and update only the changed pieces of fabric objects not all, this saved me from 100 000 sql update , to serveral handreds, that was big flaw in my backend .    `json problm` i changed as @JohnWeisz suggested i made the stringify at a different time which when user press save , and dialog of confirmation appears this saved me som time . as UX

Comment: But the size on front end `STAYED THE SAME` so its not solved. but in re write i will do it like we only send the pieces we changed in front end to backend only. and make some templates so i save repetitive attributes in JSON string.

Comment: @shareef I believe you could replicate this logic for the frontend, and keep track which parts were modified, then only send those back to the server.

Comment: @JohnWeisz Exactly that what we will do when we rewrite , it will be more dynamic for example after each change it will update some session tracking socket kind of . so we learn from our mistakes

Comment: Have you considered using protobuf to communicate ?
It is not much faster, but still faster

https://auth0.com/blog/beating-json-performance-with-protobuf/

Maybe in your scenario the gains can be larger than on this sample, it may be worth giving it a try

Comment: If an issue is sending a lot of data, you may want to compress it before sending. Maybe use some fast algo.

Comment: Try protobuf, it will faster than json

Comment: Have a look at this article, it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676439/an-alternative-method-for-json-stringify

Answer (score 2):

As commenters said - there is no way to make parsing faster.

If the concern is that the app is blocked while it's stringifying/parsing then try to split data into separate objects, stringily them and assemble back into one object before saving on the server.

If loading time of the app is not a problem you could try to ad-hoc incremental change on top of the existing app.

- ... App loading
- Load map data
- Make full copy of the data
- ... End loading
- ... App working without changes
- ... When saving changes
- diff copy with changed data to get JSON diff
- send changes (much smaller then full data)
- ... On server
- apply JSON diff changes on the server to the full data stored on server
- save changed data

I used json-diff https://github.com/andreyvit/json-diff to calc changes, and there are few analogs.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing is a slow process. If what you want is to POST a 10MB object, turn it into a file, a blob, or a buffer. Send that file/blob/buffer using formdata instead of application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)

[An example using express/multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Comment: The question is about "large objects". Therefore, there won't be a significant performance boost with the mentioned library. A quote from the `fast-json-stringify` project: "fast-json-stringify is significantly faster than JSON.stringify() for small payloads. Its performance advantage shrinks as your payload grows."

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Well just as most big "repeatable" problems go, you could use async!

But wait, isn't JS still single-threaded even when it does async... yes... but you can use ***Service-Workers*** to get true async and serialize an object way faster by parallelizing the process.

### General Approach

#### mainPage.js

```js
//= Functions / Classes =============================================================|
// To tell JSON stringify that this is already processed, don't touch
class SerializedChunk {
  constructor(data){this.data = data}
  toJSON() {return this.data}
}

// Attach all events and props we need on workers to handle this use case
const mapCommonBindings = w => {
  w.addEventListener('message', e => w._res(e.data), false)
  w.addEventListener('error', e => w._rej(e.data), false)
  w.solve = obj => {
    w._state && await w._state.catch(_=>_) // Wait for any older tasks to complete if there is another queued
    w._state = new Promise((_res, _rej) => {
      // Give this object promise bindings that can be handled by the event bindings
      // (just make sure not to fire 2 errors or 2 messages at the same time)
      Object.assign(w, {_res, _rej})
    })
    w.postMessage(obj)
    return await w._state // Return the final output, when we get the `message` event
  }
}

//= Initialization ===================================================================|
// Let's make our 10 workers
const workers = Array(10).fill(0).map(_ => new Worker('worker.js'))
workers.forEach(mapCommonBindings)

// A helper function that schedules workers in a round-robin
workers.schedule = async task => {
  workers._c = ((workers._c || -1) + 1) % workers.length
  const worker = workers[workers._c]
  return await worker.solve(task)
}
// A helper used below that takes an object key, value pair and uses a worker to solve it
const _asyncHandleValuePair = async ([key, value]) => [key, new SerializedChunk(
  await workers.schedule(value)
)]

//= Final Function ===================================================================|
// The new function (You could improve the runtime by changing how this function schedules tasks)
// Note! This is async now, obviously
const jsonStringifyThreaded = async o => {
  const f_pairs = await Promise.all(Object.entries(o).map(_asyncHandleValuePair))

  // Take all final processed pairs, create a new object, JSON stringify top level
  final = f_pairs.reduce((o, ([key, chunk]) => (
    o[key] = chunk,  // Add current key / chunk to object
    o                // Return the object to next reduce
  ), {})             // Seed empty object that will contain all the data
  return JSON.stringify(final)
}

/* lot of other code, till the function that actually uses this code */

async function submitter() {
  // other stuff
  const payload = await jsonStringifyThreaded(input.value)
  await server.send(payload)
  console.log('Done!')
}
```

#### worker.js

```js
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  const obj = e.data
  self.postMessage(JSON.stringify(obj))
}, false)
```

### Notes:

This works the following way:

- Creates a list of 10 workers, and adds a few methods and props to them

  - We care about `async .solve(Object): String` which solves our tasks using promises while masking away callback hell
- Use a new method: `async jsonStringifyThreaded(Object): String` which does the `JSON.stringify` asynchronously

  - We break the object into entries and solve each one parallelly (*this can be optimized to be recursive to a certain depth, use best judgement :)*)
  - Processed chunks are cast into `SerializedChunk` which the `JSON.stringify` will use as is, and not try to process (*since it has `.toJSON()`*)
  - Internally if the number of keys exceeds the workers, we round-robin back to the first worker and overschedule them (remember, they can handle queued tasks)

### Optimizations

You may want to consider a few more things to improve performance:

- Use of [Transferable Objects](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-transferrables) which will decrease the overhead of passing objects to service workers significantly
- Redesign `jsonStringifyThreaded()` to schedule more objects at deeper levels.

Comment: thanks for detailed answer, it just needs proof of concept, from online tooling jsfiddle and benchmark it ))

Comment: Besides some little bugs like `await is only valid in async function` for the content inside `w.solve = obj => {...}` and a missing `)` after `final = f_pairs.reduce(...)` this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can explore libraries like fast-json-stringify which use a template schema and use it while converting the json object, to boost the performance. Check the below article.

https://developpaper.com/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-json-stringify/